# The phpmyadmin cannot be accessed

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I got problem with phpmyadmin. How to solve this??

[image: phpMyAdmin Error]

I'm newbies and really hope to get help from everyone.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory. The host you're trying to connect to is wrong.

Comment: There tons of answers for such questions, Try google instead..!

Answer (score 0):

Use IP address, not hostname. Make sure your server is responding(online).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can't resolve the host name Maybe DNS problems, host is unreachable...

Try to use IP address instead of host name. or you can ping the host name to check.